# Create an entry from an extension?

Tags: channel-entries, add-on-development, query

Is it possible to use the model service to create a new entry?

I have been using the model service recently to update and delete channel entries, but can't figure out how to create.

```
$update_query = ee('Model')->get('ChannelEntry', $id_to_update)
                           ->first();

$update_query->set(array(
    'field_id_x' => 'Content',
    'field_id_x' => 'Content'
));
$update_query->save();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, obviously it is possible to use the model to create a new entry. To create a new entry using model you should follow below syntax.

```
$entry = ee('Model')->make('ChannelEntry');
$entry->Channel = $channel;
$entry->site_id =  ee()->config->item('site_id');
$entry->author_id = ee()->session->userdata('member_id');
$entry->ip_address = ee()->session->userdata['ip_address'];
$entry->versioning_enabled = $channel->enable_versioning;
$entry->sticky = FALSE;
$entry->set($entryFieldArray);           /* Array of entry_data */
$entry->title = $title;
$entry->url_title = $url_title;
$entry->entry_date = ee()->localize->now;
$entry->edit_date = ee()->localize->now;
$entry->save();
```

This way by using `ee('Model')->make('ChannelEntry')` you can create new entry. I hope this will works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Harsh. I have been trying to get this to work. I keep getting: "Undefined variable: channel". I tried changing '$entry->Channel' to '$entry->channel' but still the same. Any ideas?

Comment: Here `$channel` means `Channel ID`. All other respective variables you need to change according to it's usage like `$title` and `$url_title`.